# Initialize C array to custom character

Tags: c, winsock2

I have built a Winsock2 server. Part of that program has a function that receives data from clients. Originally the receive function I built would peek at the incoming data and determine if there was any additional data to be read before allowing `recv()` to pull the data from the buffer. This worked fine in the beginning of the project but I am now working on improving performance.

Here is a portion of the code I've written to eliminate the use of peek:

```
    unsigned char recv_buffer[4096];
    unsigned char *pComplete_buffer = malloc(sizeof(recv_buffer) * sizeof(unsigned char*));
    int offset = 0;
    int i = 0;

    ...

    for (i; i <= sizeof(recv_buffer); i++) {
        if (recv_buffer[i] == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        pComplete_buffer[offset] = recv_buffer[i];
        offset++;
    }

    ...
```

This code would work great but the problem is that `NULL == 0`. If the client happens to send a `0` this loop will break prematurely. I thought I would be clever and leave the data uninitialized to `0xcc` and use that to determine the end of `recv_buffer` but it seems that clients sometimes send that as part of their data as well.

Question:

Is there a character I can initialize `recv_buffer` to and reliably break on?

If not, is there another way I can eliminate the use of peek?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution is to keep track of how many bytes you store in `recv_buffer` to begin with.  `sizeof()` gives you the TOTAL POSSIBLE size of the buffer, but it does not tell you HOW MANY bytes actually contain valid data.

`recv()` tells you how many bytes it returns to you.  When you `recv()` data into `recv_buffer`, use that return value to increment a variable you define to indicate the number of valid bytes in `recv_buffer`.

For example:

```
unsigned char recv_buffer[4096];
int num_read, recv_buffer_size = 0;

const int max_cbuffer_size = sizeof(recv_buffer) * sizeof(unsigned char*);
unsigned char *pComplete_buffer = malloc(max_cbuffer_size);

...

num_read = recv(..., recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer), ...);
if (num_read <= 0) {
    // error handling...
    return;
}
recv_buffer_size = num_read;

...

int available = max_cbuffer_size - offset;
int num_to_copy = min(recv_buffer_size, available);

memcpy(pComplete_buffer + offset, recv_buffer, num_to_copy);
offset += num_to_copy;
memmove(recv_buffer, recv_buffer + num_to_copy, recv_buffer_size - num_to_copy);
recv_buffer_size -= num_to_copy;

...
```

Comment: Hey Remy! I think there may be a misunderstanding surrounding the question. In my real code, the `offset` variable does exactly what you are describing. The problem is not with determining how many bytes of data I've received. The problem is determining when to stop looping on `recv()` without peeking. Since the data returned from `recv()` is variable, it's difficult to determine what is the "end" without peeking. If I break the `recv()` loop prematurely I'll have incomplete data. I need a condition to reliably break the `recv()` loop.

Comment: @Corey TCP is a **streaming** transport that has no concept of "messages". That has to be handled at the application layer. Inside the transmitted data itself, each "message" MUST be framed in such a way that the receiver knows when the message ends. Either by 1) prefixing the message with its length (before the message, or inside the message's header) so the receiver can stop reading when that many bytes have been read, or 2) terminating the message with a unique delimiter so the receiver can stop reading when it has reached the delimiter. Every TCP protocol does one of these in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a character I can initialize recv_buffer to and reliably break on?

Nope. If the other side can send any character at any time, you'll have to examine them.

If you know the sender will never send *two* `NUL`s in a row (`\0\0`), you could check for that. But then some day the sender will decide to do that.

If you can change the message structure, I'd send the message length first (as a byte, network-ordered short or int depending on your protocol). Then, after parsing that length, the receiver will know exactly how long to keep reading.
Also if you're using `select`, that will block until there's something to read or the socket closes (mostly -- read the docs).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. In that example if I attempted to break on two `NULL`s I cannot determine if one or two of those bytes were part of the original payload. Failing to send the original payload can lead to deadlocks on `select()` as the server thinks it's done relaying data while the client waits in anticipation for it's final bit of information (this is a transparent proxy). Thanks for the help, Gary!

Comment: Use the return value of recv as detailed by Remy's answer.  Or design a proper protocol to encapsulate  and describe the data.  Usually both are called for.